# sibling divs jump to new line when resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am creating 3 rows and each rows having 4 column in it. But what i am trying to achieve is that when 1 resize any column in a row then remaining columns should resize according to total remaining width of row.
Let assume that if total width of row is 100% and if i resize 1st column by 60% then remaining three column should resize according to remaining 40%.
As in my html it doesnot resizes the remaining column moves down.

Here is my code.

```
<div id="data-1">
            <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="column" style="float: left; overflow: hidden; min-width: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%; float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%;float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%;float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="column" style="float: left; overflow: hidden; min-width: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%; float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%;float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%;float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="column" style="float: left; overflow: hidden; min-width: 25%;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%; float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%;float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            <div class="column" style="min-width: 25%;float: left; overflow: hidden;"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

According to this i get below structure:

[image]

But when i resize one column then i get this:

[image]

I want to achieve this when resize:

[image]

Comment: i think you want to this check tothis and resize than check http://jsfiddle.net/af52nnyj/3/

Answer (score 1):

Used to
**CSS Media Queries**  and

`display` `table` and `display` `table-cell` **as like this**

**Css**

```
  .row{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.column{
    display:table-cell;
    height:20px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}


@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    #data-1 .row:first-child> .column:first-child{width:60%;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="data-1">
            <div class="row" ">
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ">
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ">
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            <div class="column" ></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/af52nnyj/3/)**

**[more info about media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)**

Comment: Thanks for it let me check

Comment: but it can be resize at any size@Rohit it could be 40% 50% or 90% too.
a suser can also resize any column it could be column 2 or 4 any.

Comment: thanks @Rohit for you help i have tried it but when i am resizing any other column the remaining not changes as for resize  am using jquery.